# Init/Enter/Exit context manager analogue in groovy?

Tags: groovy

I am wondering what is the groovy way to accomplish something similar to Python's context manager, with it's init, enter and exit methods. Here is the basic example in Python:

```
class ContextManager(): 
    def __init__(self): 
        print('init method called') 

    def __enter__(self): 
        print('enter method called') 
        return self

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_value, exc_traceback): 
        print('exit method called') 


with ContextManager() as manager: 
    print('with statement block')
```

Output:

```
init method called
enter method called
with statement block
exit method called
```

Comment: Just because it uses the same word doesn't mean it has the same functionality - `.with` in Groovy just gives a context to a closure, there's no "enter" or "exit" hook.

Comment: init - it's just a class constructor, enter/exit corresponds to try/finally (ihmo).

Answer (score 4):

If you need your own entry points, you can write your own base class to steer this behaviour.

```
class ContextManager {
    ContextManager() { println "init" }
    void enter() { println "enter" }
    void exit(Throwable t=null) { println "exit ${t?:""}" }
    String getInner() { "inner" }

    final run(Closure f) {
        try {
            enter()
            f(this)
            exit()
        }
        catch (Throwable t) {
            exit(t)
        }
    }
}

def outer = "outer"

new ContextManager().run { manager ->
    println outer
    println manager.inner
    println "body"
}
```

Output:

```
init
enter
outer
inner
body
exit
```

Answer (score 0):

Groovy can accomplish something similar to this for the enter and exit using metaprogramming. Groovy has both runtime and compile-time metaprogramming. With runtime metaprogramming, you could do something similar by using invokeMethod in a class.

- [InvokeMethod Docs](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/documentation/core-metaprogramming.html#_invokemethod)
- [Example](http://larmog.github.io/2014/08/18/simple-groovy-aop-using-mop/)

Compile-time metaprogramming is a bit more difficult because you are dealing at the compiler level:

- [Documentation](http://groovy-lang.org/metaprogramming.html#developing-ast-xforms)
- [Simple Example](http://blog.kartikshah.com/2009/07/groovy-ast-transformation-aop-style.html)

I made a Grails plugin, which would be a much more complicated example, that allows me to do something similar but invoking closures around methods:

- [Source](https://github.com/virtualdogbert/Enforcer)
- [Test app](https://github.com/virtualdogbert/testEnforcer33)

Hope some of this helps...